# FreeRADIUS Perl script to perform local lookup, then proxy if required

Tags: freeradius

I am attempting to use FreeRADIUS to perform a local DB lookup (MAC address), if no results are found return a CoA to the device to provision a captive portal, however if results are found to then manipulate the attributes on the request (add username/password from DB) and proxy the request onto another RADIUS server

Is this advanced logic possible? I have found some examples to pre/post process a proxy request, but not control if the request should be processed locally or proxied etc

Answer (score 0):

in authorize you should be able to set the realm (used for proxy) after preprocess and before your realm module gets processed.

https://networkradius.com/doc/3.0.10/raddb/sites-available/default.html